# SSL certificate not working on debian 8

Tags: debian, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I installed certificate ok but configuration it seems be broken ...Whats wrong?
In ports.conf of course I have Listen 443

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine on

     ServerAdmin admin@example.com
     ServerName domain.eu
     DocumentRoot /var/www/a/public

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you include the error output?

Comment: Maybe server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this config without:

```
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
```